# SLF4J Multiple bindings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logback, slf4j

I've come across the `SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings` error in scala. I know there are lot of forums and discussions about this and this warning is not my problem. I can get rid of the warning by excluding one of the conflicting entries in my build.sbt. In my case, the conflicting packages are `org.slf4j` and `ch.qos.logback`. So, I can get rid of the warning by entering one of the following in my build.sbt.

```
libraryDependencies ~= {_.map(_.exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic"))}
```

or

```
libraryDependencies ~= {_.map(_.exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"))}
```

My issue is, when I get rid of this warning it messes up the output in the windows command prompt (Yes, this needs to run on windows).

Excluding `org.slf4j` shows weird characters in the command window. These characters are not displayed in my intelliJ console.

[image]

if I exclude `ch.qos.logback`, the output looks fine but the command prompt doesn't display any log messages below error level.

[image]

I think I want to exclude `org.slf4j` so I can configure my loggers easily using `logback.xml`. Does anyone have any idea on why there are weird characters on command line in the first case and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those weird signs are ANSI escape sequences for text coloring and formatting. Probably your logback layout configuration has some coloring enabled. For more details see: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#coloring

Comment: Thank you so much. This was my exact problem.